# What's wrong with this javascript code? (body script calling head function)

Tags: javascript

Why does the following not produce any result? I get a blank page. I kept modifying/simplifying the code to see where the problem is and it seems to be with the line

```
"var count = NbnamePattern(names)"
```

Things seem to work when the body script calls a function defined in the head but *with no arguments* passed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Assignment 2 Q4</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    function NbnamePattern(var names) {
      var count = 0;
      for (var i in names) {
        if (names[i].search(/ie$/) != -1 || names[i].search(/y$/) != -1)
          count++;
      }
      return count;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>
  <script type="text/javaScript">
    var names = new Array("freddie", "bob", "mieke", "yahoo2", "georgey"); var count = NbnamePattern(names); document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "The number of names having these two patterns (/ie$/) and (/y$) in the array is:" + count;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `function NbnamePattern(var names){ ... ` is a syntax error. Remove the `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function NbnamePattern(var names){
            var count = 0;
            for(var i in names)
                if(names[i].search(/ie$/) != -1 || names[i].search(/y$/) != -1)
                    count++;
            return count;
        }
```

should be

```
function NbnamePattern(names){
            var count = 0;
            for(var i in names)
                if(names[i].search(/ie$/) != -1 || names[i].search(/y$/) != -1)
                    count++;
            return count;
        }
```

The functions in javascript dont take types, it should just be name

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the `var` from `NbnamePattern(var names)` function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Assignment 2 Q4</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    function NbnamePattern(names) {
      var count = 0;
      for (var i in names) {
        if (names[i].search(/ie$/) != -1 || names[i].search(/y$/) != -1)
          count++;
      }
      return count;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>
  <script type="text/javaScript">
    var names = new Array("freddie", "bob", "mieke", "yahoo2", "georgey"); var count = NbnamePattern(names); document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "The number of names having these two patterns (/ie$/) and (/y$) in the array is:" + count;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```